# How to fetch list of CKRecordIDs

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'd like to be able to download a list of all CKRecordIDs of a certain record type from a Cloud Kit database.  I don't want the records themselves, since they have large assets that aren't needed until the user asks for them.

CKQuery seems to return CKRecords only.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you could use a CKQueryOperation and set the desiredKeys to the fields that you do want to return. I'm not sure if you can set it to an empty array. Since you only want the CKRecordID's and those are already in the meta data you would not need any fields. If it does not work, then just fetch one small field.